# Can I do two actions separated by a delay of 30 minutes?

Tags: if-this-then-that, automation

I would like to use IFTTT to turn on an outside light when triggered and then, automatically after 30 minutes, turn off the light.  The trigger would be an SMS message and the switch is a Belkin WeMo Insight.

This would require a single trigger to initiate an action (turn the light on), then a delay timer (30 minutes) and then a second action (turn the light off).

Is this possible or is there some other similar service that can do this?

Comment: You can try this approach http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33674/ifttt-can-you-specify-a-delay-for-an-action/73420#73420 using google cal events